# Taking sine of each row for a specific column python for all files in a directory

Tags: python, bash, numpy

I have large number of files with different line numbers and same column numbers in a directory.I want to loop through all the files and take the sine of the last two column. When I apply the code below, it works for a file only. If I want to make this operation for all files in a directory, what I have to do?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("input.dat", delimiter=",")
result = np.sin(data[:,-2:])
np.savetxt("output.dat", result, fmt="%.2f", delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Use `os.listdir()` or something similar.

Comment: `usecols` could let you load just that column(s), saving the `data[:,-2:]` step.  It's easy to loop through each of the input files.  Do you want output to different files, or collect things in one?

Comment: I want output to same files.  Only specific column will change and other columns will remain same.

Comment: The shown code doesn't change **only** _a specific column_ - it changes the last two columns and removes all others. You have to make code and question consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume we have a directory "mydir" in current directory and the `*.dat`
files are stored in "mydir". As we do not want to overwrite the `*.dat` files,
let's create a new directory "outdir" to put the results with the same filenames.

The directory structure will look like:

```
./ --- mydir/
         |
         +--- file1.dat
         +--- file2.dat
         +--- ...
         +--- outdir/
               |
               +--- file1.dat
               +--- file2.dat
               +--- ...
```

Then please try the following:

```
import numpy as np
import glob, os

if not os.path.exists("mydir/outdir"):
    os.makedirs("mydir/outdir")     # can use "exist_ok=True" option for python 3.2 or later
for f in glob.glob("mydir/*.dat"):
    basename = os.path.basename(f)
    data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=",")
    result = np.sin(data[:,-2:])
    np.savetxt("mydir/outdir/" + basename, result, fmt="%.2f", delimiter=",")
```

Please modify the directory names according to your environment.

[Edit]
Assuming you want to modify the rightmost two columns `data[:,-2:]`, please try instead:

```
import numpy as np
import glob, os

if not os.path.exists("mydir/outdir"):
    os.makedirs("mydir/outdir")     # can use "exist_ok=True" option for python 3.2 or later
for f in glob.glob("mydir/*.dat"):
    basename = os.path.basename(f)
    data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=",")
    data[:,-2:] = np.sin(data[:,-2:])
    np.savetxt("mydir/outdir/" + basename, data, fmt="%.2f", delimiter=",")
```

Comment: It actually works, but I have only two columns that returned to sine in output files. To have also other columns that will remain same, and this will like this, x= data[:,:-2]. How can I concatenate them, append or something like this?

Comment: I've updated my answer to take sine's of the rightmost two columns sliced by `data[:,-2:]` based on your original post. If your columns in interest differ than that as `data[:,:-2]`, please modify the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this function will help you, you give her the file extension (dat) in your situation and the file name (input) in your situation.

```
files = return_folder_files("dat", "input")
for file in files:
    data = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter=",")
    result = np.sin(data[:,-2:])
    np.savetxt("output.dat", result, fmt="%.2f", delimiter=",")


def return_folder_files(extension, folder_name):
    import os
    files = []
    for file in os.listdir(str(os.getcwd())+"/"+str(folder_name)):
        if file.endswith("."+str(extension)):
            files.append(file)
    return files
```

Comment: By this way, I can handle all files in directory, but how can I apply operation on these files?

Comment: The thing that I dont understand why we use input and output names. These names are examples only. All dat file names are different and I have hundreds of files. With 'input' name do you mean directory name?

Comment: you need to put all the hundreads of files in folder named input(this folder should be in your current working directory and this code should work.

Comment: YES i ment directory name